# Protocol declaration warning

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, delegates, protocols

MPPopoverControllerDelegate.h file

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@class MPPopoverController;

@protocol MPPopoverControllerDelegate <NSObject>    
@optional
- (void)popoverControllerDidDismissPopover:(MPPopoverController *)popoverController;
@end
```

MPPopoverController.h file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@protocol MPPopoverControllerDelegate;

@interface MPPopoverController : UIViewController <MPPopoverControllerDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, assign) id<MPPopoverControllerDelegate> delegate;

@end
```

MPPopoverController.m file

```
#import "MPPopoverController.h"
#import "MPPopoverControllerDelegate.h"

@implementation MPPopoverController
@end
```

`@property (nonatomic, assign) id<MPPopoverControllerDelegate> delegate;` : this line has warning

> Cannot find protocol definition for 'MPPopoverControllerDelegate'

What is wrong? And how to fix this warning?
if replace '@protocol MPPopoverControllerDelegate'; with '#import "MPPopoverControllerDelegate.h', everything will be ok.
 But [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocProtocols.html) - in Referring to Other Protocols you can see that apple says to use @protocol

Comment: missing a `#import "MPPopoverControllerDelegate.h"` ?

Comment: @Vince looks like he's trying to use a forward declaration. As long as his .m file includes the file, he should be fine.

Comment: Where are you including your .h?

Comment: if replace '@protocol MPPopoverControllerDelegate'; with '#import "MPPopoverControllerDelegate.h', everything will be ok.<br/> But [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocProtocols.html) - in Referring to Other Protocols you can see that apple says to use @protocol

Comment: It's always better to use forward declarations for classes and protocols and import your files in your .m file. It avoids circular includes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there an absolute need for your protocol declaration to be in a different header file? Unless it's quite a large protocol definition (which yours isn't), I would suggest declaring it below your interface declaration.

**MPPopoverController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@protocol MPPopoverControllerDelegate;

@interface MPPopoverController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, assign) id<MPPopoverControllerDelegate> delegate;

@end


@protocol MPPopoverControllerDelegate <NSObject>    
@optional
- (void)popoverControllerDidDismissPopover:(MPPopoverController *)popoverController;
@end
```

Comment: Yes I can. But I don't understand why external protocol declaration  makes warning.

Comment: I don't either, and it shouldn't really, but this solution would fix your build warning so it shouldn't be worth dwelling on.

Comment: Still warning '@interface MPPopoverController : NSObject <MPPopoverControllerDelegate>'. You solution doesn't help.

Comment: Why does your `UIViewController` subclass implement the protocol? I've updated my post with a change that may help.

Comment: Thank's I didn't saw that. Thank's that help.

Comment: I have the same issue - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12892463/ios-5-0-warning-cannot-find-protocol-definition-for-delegate I did exactly the same but still I see warning message. Why shouldn't I implement my protocol? How would I check for conforms to protocol then? Am I missing anything? Could you help please.

Comment: @AppleDeveloper I've posted an answer to your question

Comment: @EllNeal, "Why does your `UIViewController` subclass implement the protocol?" Isn't this the way delegates work?

Answer (score 2):

Compiler read your .m file, and load .h files when necessary. So it loads `MPPopoverController.h` first and when it read it delegate protocol is still undeclared. You could easily fix this warning just by swapping include lines. To let compiler read delegate .h file first.

```
#import "MPPopoverControllerDelegate.h"
#import "MPPopoverController.h"

@implementation MPPopoverController
@end
```

Comment: then your delegate .h file contain #import "MPPopoverController.h" line. but in code from your question it doesn't.

Answer (score -1):

Are you sure you're ever including MPPopoverControllerDelegate.h somewhere?

Comment: @TerenteIonutAlexandru - I'm not sure the point here is finding who downvoted you, but rather how to solve OP's issue. Also, don't guess wrong.

Comment: I add it in my MPPopoverController.m file

Comment: @Terente Huh? I pointed out an error in your code, that's pretty much it. By the way, your code still won't work. Maybe I should go ahead and down vote it too?

Comment: NO. MPPopoverControllerDelegate.h file was decelerated in MPPopoverController.m file before I posted my question.

Answer (score -1):

Import MPPopoverControllerDelegate.h in MPPopoverController.h and MPPopoverController.h should look like:

The code copy pasted from the question and edited was removed. The following code is copy pasted from xcode.

The MPPopoverControllerDelegate.h:

```
@class MPPopoverController;

@protocol MPPopoverControllerDelegate <NSObject>    

@optional

- (void)popoverControllerDidDismissPopover:(MPPopoverController *)popoverController;

@end
```

The MPPopoverController.h

```
@protocol MPPopoverControllerDelegate;


@interface MPPopoverController : UIViewController{

    id<MPPopoverControllerDelegate> delegate;
}

@property (nonatomic, assign) id<MPPopoverControllerDelegate> delegate;


@end
```

The MPPopoverController.m

```
@implementation MPPopoverController

@synthesize delegate;
//rest of view controller class.
```

The problem is that in your MPPopoverController  interface you specify  `<MPPopoverControllerDelegate>`. This means that the class implements this protocol! Is wrong because the class is the owner of the protocol. So your logic is wrong in some point.