# iOS 5.0 Warning: Cannot find protocol definition for Delegate

Tags: objective-c, ios5, protocols, forward-declaration

I have custom UIView class GestureView. I have a forward declaration for this class and it's delegate below. I have imported GestureView.h in .m file. This works fine but iOS gives warning message saying "Cannot find protocol definition for GestureViewDelegate". If I remove forward declaration it gives same warning message as error. I don't want to import  GestureView.h from ContainerViewController.h as I usually imports stuffs in .m file. Could someone please explain what's wrong in following class structure?

**ContainerViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class DividerView;
@class GestureView;
@protocol GestureViewDelegate;

@interface ContainerViewController : UIViewController<GestureViewDelegate>
   @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet GestureView *topContentView;
@end
```

**GestureView.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@protocol GestureViewDelegate;

@interface GestureView : UIView
    - (void)initialiseGestures:(id)delegate;
@end

@protocol GestureViewDelegate <NSObject>
@required
- (void)GestureView:(GestureView*)view handleSignleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)recognizer;
@end
```

Comment: Where is your protocol defined?

Comment: You can see in the code I posted! It's in GestureView.h!

Comment: In `ContainerViewController.h` try `#import GestureView.h` instead of the forward declaration

Comment: I mentioned that I don't want to do that! Please let me know if you know what's wrong with the forward declaration. Thanks.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I like that you're trying to avoid imports in header files: very good practice. However, to fix your bug you can just make your code even better! In my opinion it's not really necessary that your `ContainerViewController` class outwardly declares that it supports `GestureViewDelegate` protocol, so you should move this into your implementation file. Like so:

**GestureView.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


@protocol GestureViewDelegate;

@interface GestureView : UIView

- (void)initialiseGestures:(id <GestureViewDelegate>)delegate;

@end


@protocol GestureViewDelegate <NSObject>
@required

- (void)gestureView:(GestureView *)view handleSingleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer;

@end
```

**ContainerViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


@class GestureView;

@interface CollectionViewController : UIViewController

// this property is declared as readonly because external classes don't need to modify the value (I guessed seen as it was an IBOutlet)
@property (strong, nonatomic, readonly) GestureView *topContentView;

@end
```

**ContainerViewController.m**

```
#import "ContainerViewController.h"
#import "GestureView.h"


// this private interface declares that GestureViewDelegate is supported
@interface CollectionViewController () <GestureViewDelegate>

// the view is redeclared in the implementation file as readwrite and IBOutlet
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet GestureView *topContentView;

@end


@implementation ContainerViewController

// your implementation code goes here

@end
```

Comment: Awesome Neal! I understood your solution and it does make completely sense to me but I am wondering how other protocols like UITableView-Delegate and Datasource have been implemented? You can implement them in the header file declaration itself! Isn't there anyway we can create our custom protocols such that when you implement it, you have to override @required methods? If we don't implement them then there is no point of having protocols at all. I can simply remove protocol delegate variable altogether from the ContainerViewController and just pass it's id in initialiseGestures.

Comment: Moreover, iOS compiler shouldn't give warning message at all in this case. The forward declarations are meant to avoid compile time warnings and errors! Aren't they?

Comment: While this works, it's more clear to have the supported delegates listed in one place - the header file where all the standard delegates are listed. E.g., in my `.h` file I might have `<UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>`, ideally I want to put ALL the delegates there. How is this done?

Comment: @TRedman My advice in this situation would be to declare `GestureViewDelegate` in a separate header file (e.g. `GestureViewDelegate.h`), which can be imported in the implementing header file (whereas the class itself could be forward declared).

Answer (score 0):

Try this way, and please reply if it works or not.

GestureView.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@protocol GestureViewDelegate <NSObject>
@required
- (void)GestureView:(GestureView*)view handleSignleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)recognizer;
@end

@interface GestureView : UIView
    - (void)initialiseGestures:(id)delegate;
@end
```

ContainerView.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class DividerView;
@class GestureView;
/*@protocol GestureViewDelegate;*/ //NO NEED TO WRITE THIS

@interface ContainerViewController : UIViewController<GestureViewDelegate>
   @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet GestureView *topContentView;
@end
```

Comment: Nope it doesn't work. I already tried that. It gives same warning message as ERROR!